# How to serialize complex object containing DateTime with /Date()

Tags: c#, json, date, serialization, restsharp

I would like to serialize an object like this into JSON:

```
 ConcreteClassA classA = GetContreteClassA();
 var request = Helper.GetRestRequest("Insert", Method.POST);
 request.JsonSerializer = new ConcreteClasseAJsonSerializer();
 request.AddJsonBody(new { abClass = classA, useBasicProcess = true });
 IRestResponse<AbstractClass> response = _restClient.Execute<AbstractClass>(request);
 if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
     Helper.ThrowExeption(response);
```

With this code, I get the error:

> An error occurs while deserializing the parameter abClass. the content of DateTime doesn't start with '/Date(' and doesn't finish with ')/' as expected by json.

This is the JSON generated by this code and there is no `"/Date("` for `DateMod` property.

```
{"abClass":{"__type":"ConcreteClassA:http://www.test.com/WBS","Type":1,"Number":"FA8E5E78E70F04EB","Rate":7.85,"Name":"Toto",
"Qualite":"Société","DateMod":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},"useBasicProcess":true}
```

Here is the code for the Serialize method of `ConcreteClassAJsonSerializer`:

```
public string Serialize(object obj)
{
    var binder = new ConcreteClassATypeNameSerializationBinder();
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
        SerializationBinder = binder,
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    });

    jsonString = jsonString.Replace("\"$type\":\"\",", string.Empty);
    jsonString = jsonString.Replace("$type", "__type");
    return jsonString;
    }
}
```

And the code for the BindToName method of the binder:

```
public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
{
    if (serializedType == typeof(ConcreteClassA) || serializedType == typeof(ConcreteClassB) || serializedType == typeof(ConcreteClassC))
    {
        assemblyName = null;
        typeName = serializedType.Name + ":" + TypeFormat;
        return;
    }
    assemblyName = null;
    typeName = null;
}
```

I have to use this custom serializer and binder in order to specify the concrete class of the abstract class `abClass`.
But how can I add the missing `\/Date(` in that serialization process?